# How do I test if a fasta file exists in bash?

Tags: bash, file, fasta

I am working with fasta files in a bash script. Before starting it, I would like to check that I have a file in fasta format.
Let's say I have this file:

```
>seq1
ASVNJF
>seq2
PNGRW
```

I was trying

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [[ $text_file =~ ^(>).+\n[A-Z\n] ]]
then
echo "It is not a fasta file"
fi
```

But it is not working. Any ideas for it?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

`[[ $text_file =~ ^(>).+\n[A-Z\n] ]]` compares the value of `$text_file` which is probably the file's name, not its contents.

You can use the following Perl one-liner to check the files:

```
perl -ne '
    $id = />.+/;
    die "Empty $.\n" if $id && $p || $id && eof;
    $p = $id;
    die "Invalid char $1 ($.)\n" if !$id && /([^A-Z\n])/
    ' -- file.seq
```

It stores whether there is an id on the current line in the variable $id. $p stores the previous $id, which guards against two consecutive id lines. If the current line doesn't contain an id but contains something else than A-Z or a newline, the second error is reported. The special variable `$.` contains the current input line number.

To make the shell script exit when the Perl command fails, you need to tell the shell script to exit. Just add `|| exit 1` after the Perl command:

```
perl -ne '...' -- file.seq || exit 1
```

Comment: Thanks! @choroba It seems to work. But, when I get the message because it is not a fasta format file, the script keeps runing. Is there a perl line to exit the script?

Comment: `die` should stop the script. Why do you think it's still running? Or do you mean the shell script?

Comment: I think is the shell script @choroba. When I introduce a file without fasta format, the following commands keep running. It is not like ```exit``` in a shell script.

Comment: Thanks! @choroba I saw your update, but, I'm having an error. It detects when a file has no fasta format and the shell script exits, but, when there is a fasta format file it also exits. I tried to change ```||``` to ```|``` and it seem to work.

Comment: What does it say when it exits with a correct fasta file? Using `|` is definitely not correct.

Comment: Yeah sorry @choroba, I changed one line and it seemed to work, but it didn't. Using ```||```the shell scripts exists. Thank you so much!

Comment: "Thank you" on StackOverflow = upvote / accept.